# Generate whatsapp stickers from PC without any app

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am newbie when it comes to whatsapp stickers, and I don't know about how stickers work.

But I am using a linux desktop where I have written a basic ruby script that could convert svg to webp, multithreaded. In a loop, it reads certain folders with svgs.

I have have 30 svgs in 4 folders, total 120 stickers. I want myself and people to add possibly a thousand more over time.

Currently I am used to copy the directory containing webp files to my android phone, use sticker.ly to manually select and generate stickers. That's too much work.

I want my script to have the sticker generator code in the loop, where it will generate stickers from svgs, I can take the packs to my phone and add them to whatsapp. That way I will be saving a lot of time.
Is it possible?